# Access Squarespace database with a MySql management application

Tags: mysql, squarespace

After creating some collection entries in Squarespace (like **Blogs**, **Events**, **Products** and so on..), is it possible to access the single databases with a MySql management application?

Or is it possible to create a private MySql database and force Squarespace to use it for the collection?

I would be easier to add/edit large data..

Answer (score 0):

Squarespace is very much a "design-first" platform, and the data structure (or at least, the data structure as we can access it) is heavily abstracted away in the name of a simple design process. Getting data in can indeed be difficult, and getting it out even more so. It's just not a platform friendly to data management or portability.

Furthermore, [you cannot run server-side code](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815358-Custom-code-FAQ). So unless you fetch, parse and display your date entirely client-side using JavaScript (bypassing Squrespace's collections/layout entirely), the only way to serve the data to users is to first enter it via Squarespace's back-end editing UI. Custom tools have been created that, for example, add a button in the backend editing UI that allows you to manually sync collection items/data with an external source. It basically reads your source, maps the data to the collection item creation API that the backend UI itself uses, then executes until all collection items have been added in the back-end. However, this process must be manually trigered, and continually done as needed by logging into the backend, running the syncing function, then waiting for it to finish.